# How to have line breaks in logic proofs?

Tags: logicproof

I am currently trying to find a way to have line breaks in a logic proof. I have several proofs that are too long and are cut off by the edge of the page.

Ideally I'm looking for a way to make the line automatically break it it gets too long, but it would also help a lot if I knew hot to make a line break manually.

So far I have tried \ \ and \newline, \makecell and \thread from the makecell package, putting the entire proof in a table with only one column with a fixed width and putting the individual lines in such tables, but nothing works.

I am sure the solution is pretty obvious, but I can't seem to find it. Below are the code for one of the proofs and a screengrab of how it looks like in the finished PDF.

```
\setlength\subproofhorizspace{2em}
\begin{logicproof}{0}
    \text{Whales are mammals. (true term)}&\\ 
    \text{Whales are mammals and humans need oxygen. (disjunction introduction version 1 of line 1, here the introduced term is true)}&\\ 
    \text{Whales are mammals and the world ended in 2012. (disjunction introduction version 1 of line 1, here the introduced term is false)}&\\
    \text{Albert Einstein is dead or whales are mammals. (disjunction introduction version 2 of line 1, here the introduced term is true)}\\
    \text{Australia doesn't exist or whales are mammals. (disjunction introduction version 2 of line 1, here the introduced term is false)}
\end{logicproof}
```

[image: image of cut off logic proof]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Without the definition of `leftproo`f it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I'm sorry, i edited it to be logicproof now. leftproof is basically the same, only that it is aligned at the righthand side of the page instead of cantered. The problem is the same for both.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\newcommand\state[1]{\parbox[t]{20em}{\sloppy#1}}
\begin{document}
\setlength\subproofhorizspace{2em}
\begin{logicproof}{0}
    \state{Whales are mammals. (true term)}&\\ 
    \state{Whales are mammals and humans need oxygen.\\ (disjunction introduction version 1 of line 1, here the introduced term is true)}&\\ 
    \state{Whales are mammals and the world ended in 2012.\\ (disjunction introduction version 1 of line 1, here the introduced term is false)}&\\
    \state{Albert Einstein is dead or whales are mammals.\\ (disjunction introduction version 2 of line 1, here the introduced term is true)}\\
    \state{Australia doesn't exist or whales are mammals.\\ (disjunction introduction version 2 of line 1, here the introduced term is false)}
\end{logicproof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly!